# Definition of derivative of $f$ at $c$

Tags: limits, derivatives

While solving a proof on "If a function $f$ is differentiable at a point $c$, then it is also continuous at that point". It is stated that

> $f$ is differentiable at $c$, we have
>   $$
> f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}
> $$

Where does it come from ?

My understanding is that
$$
f'(c)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}
$$

Comment: Those definitions are equivalent. You can also say that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if it has the form $f(x)=f(a)+C*(x-a)+r(x)$, with $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{r(x)}{x-a}=0$. And $C=f'(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $x=c+h$ we have

$$x \to c \iff h \to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you introduce the variable substitution $x=c+h$, you can see the two limits are identical.